# теорема Байеса, почему пример в википедии рассчитан именно так?

Tags: теория-вероятностей, теорема-байеса

в [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0) есть пример решения задачи по теореме Байеса под номером 4 "Парадокс теоремы Байеса".

Я пытаюсь понять почему для случая с двумя повторными проверками решение указано как 10,98%, в то время как использование расширенной версии этой теоремы дает ответ 54,99%. Для случая с одиночной проверкой оба расчета дают одинаковый результат, равный 91,7%

Для расчета итераций в расширенной версии, я подставляю рассчитанную вероятность в каждой последующей итерации, вот скрипт на Питоне

```
def bayes(PA,PBA,N):
    result = []
    for x in range(N):
        PBA = (PA*PBA)/(PA*PBA+(1-PBA)*(1-PA))
        result.append(PBA)
    return result
```

С точки зрения формул мне понятна разница в результате расчета, но для примера номер 4 из Википедии и если говорить о Байесе, ведь нужно обновить "знание" о новой условной вероятности после второго испытания? Почему это не сделано, а вместо этого просто повторно посчитаны уже ранее известные вероятности?

Comment: *ведь нужно обновить "знание" о новой условной вероятности после второго испытания?* С чего бы? Показанные вероятности - результат миллиона тестов. Миллион первый их практически не изменит.

Comment: Здесь понимается, что ситуация "идеальная". т.е. между тестами ничего не произошло и человек тот же самый. Два раза делается тест с целью выявить заболевание. 

Если вы хотите сказать, что "признанный больным при первом тесте уже больной", то это не соответствует условию задачи: сделать два последовательных теста для повышения вероятности распознавания болезни.